# How would I return output of two lines into a single line?

Tags: awk, grep, concatenation, filtering

So I currently have a file named test2.txt that shows uptime of several servers that looks like below.

```
 box1.com returned RC 0
 15:28pm  up 14 days 16:05

box2.com returned RC 0
 10:28:39 up 96 days

box3.com returned RC 0
 15:28:39 up 180 days

box4.com returned RC 0
 02:28am  up 89 days  4:49

box5.com returned RC 0
 02:28:40 up 19 days
```

Ideally I want to remove the extra fluff in the output - and have it return one line, only showing the servers that have a uptime of more than 90 days.

Ideal output:

```
box2.com up 96 days 

box3.com up 180 days
```

I have not had any luck yet and have been trying to use awk to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= '$7>90{print $1, $6, $7, $8}' file
box2.com up 96 days
box3.com up 180 days
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
 box1.com returned RC 0
 15:28pm  up 14 days 16:05

box2.com returned RC 0
 10:28:39 up 96 days

box3.com returned RC 0
 15:28:39 up 180 days

box4.com returned RC 0
 02:28am  up 89 days  4:49

box5.com returned RC 0
 02:28:40 up 19 days
```

then

```
awk '/ returned /{server=$1}/ up /&&$3>90{arr[server]=$3}END{for(i in arr){print i,"up",arr[i],"days"}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
box2.com up 96 days
box3.com up 180 days
```

Explanation: if line contains `returned` then save 1st field value in variable `server`, if line contains `up` and 3rd field value is greater than 90 I save uptime in array `arr` under key being server name. **Disclaimer** this solutions assumes unique server name and that you are accepting any order of rows in output.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filename="test2.txt"

# Using awk to parse the file and extract server name, status, and uptime
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\n" } {
    server_name = $1
    status = $6
    uptime = $7 " " $8

    printf "%s: %s %s\n", server_name, status, uptime
}' "$filename"
```

It outputs:

```
box1.com: up 14 days
box2.com: up 96 days
box3.com: up 180 days
box4.com: up 89 days
box5.com: up 19 days
```

Then you have to add the 90 days test.

Hth

Comment: `RS="\n\n"` requires GNU awk or similar which support multi-char RS. If you use `RS=""` instead then it'll work in any awk.